# How to solve src refspec dev does not match any

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push to a branch of main on Github. The branch is called prod. I do this to push

```
cd path
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First Commit"

git remote add origin 'url'
git push -u origin prod
```

When I run this i get a

error: src refspec dev does not match any

error: failed to push some refs to

Can you please help?
Thanks

Comment: Probably you have not committed your code. Verify it once.

Comment: The error you would get for the above would be `error: src refspec prod does not match any`. Note the word *prod*, not *dev*. To get `dev` here you would have to have run `git push origin dev`. Now, so that you can answer your own question, try running `git branch` to list out your branch names. What branch names exist? What branch names can you `git push`?